# break; not ending for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, break

So I have some JSON data that I'm trying to parse. The 'id: 2' is the equivalent action id of the 'like-count'. For testing purposes, I am setting the array of 'post.actions_summary' to,

```
post.actions_summary.push({id: 5, count: 2}, {id: 6, count: 2}, {id: 2, count: 10}, {id: 10, count: 10});
```

The code is supposed to parse through this array is below:

```
for (i = 0; i < post.actions_summary.length; i++ ) {
  action = post.actions_summary[i];

  if (action.id === 2) {
    aID = action.id;
    aCOUNT = action.count;
    post.actions_summary = [];
    post.actions_summary.push({id: aID, count: aCOUNT});
    break;
  } else {
    post.actions_summary = [];
    post.actions_summary.push({id: 2, count: -1});
  }
}
```

However, when checking the value of 'post.actions_summary', I keep getting an array with one element, that has 'id: 2, count: -1'. I have also tried to break out using '.some' (return false) and '.every' (return true), but that didn't work either.

The correct value of 'post.actions_summary' should be {id: 2, count: 10}.

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(action));` to see what each iteration is doing

Comment: When I put in your code just below 'action =', and before the if loop, what is returned in the web console is:

{"id":5,"count":2} |
1 |
post.actions_summary |
[Object count: -1id: 2__proto__: Object]

Comment: I actually think I may know... the '.length' is essentially 0 after the first ELSE statement, such that loop terminates on the first iteration.  I should probably try setting a variable for the .length to preserve the actual value.  Testing now.

Now I'm getting an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined(…)) , when putting, 'i < length'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

```
filtered_actions = post.actions_summary.filter(function(action){
        return action.id == 2
    });

 post.actions_summary = filtered_actions;
```

Comment: Added, if (typeof filtered_actions[0] == "undefined") {
   post.actions_summary.push({id: 2, count: 0})

}  

to provide a default value if it's not found.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you have an array of elements, and you want to get the first element which id is equals to "2" and if there is no elements which has an id equal to "2" you want to initialize your array with a default element (value equals to "-1").

If i'm right, there is an error in your algorithm: if the first element in your array is not equal to "2" you initialize your array with your default element, regardless of the size of your array, you'll always stop at the first element.

A possible solution :

```
var post = {actions_summary:[]};
post.actions_summary.push({id: 5, count: 2}, {id: 6, count: 2}, {id: 2, count: 10}, {id: 10, count: 10});
var result = []; // bad idea to edit the size of post.actions_summary array during the loop
var found = false

for (var i = 0; i < post.actions_summary.length && !found; i++ ) {
  action = post.actions_summary[i];
  found = action.id === 2;

  if (found) {
    aID = action.id;
    aCOUNT = action.count;
    result.push({id: aID, count: aCOUNT}); 
  }
}

if(!found){
    result.push({id: 2, count: -1});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

In the end, the code I am using is:

```
posts.forEach(function(post) {

  filtered_actions =

  post.actions_summary.filter(function(action){
        return action.id == 2
  });

  if (typeof filtered_actions[0] !== "undefined") {
     post.actions_summary = filtered_actions;
  } else {
     post.actions_summary = [{id: 2, count: 0}];
  }

  });
```